# How to apply webcam effects to other applications?

Tags: 11.10, video, webcam, effects

I have a webcam in my laptop.
I am user root, so I can do anything. 
The webcam works fine, everything worked out of the box.
I can access it from Cheese and apply effects.
I can also access the webcam from Skype (as `/dev/video0`)

But what I can't do, is apply an effect in Cheese (specifically the effect saturation, which produces a much better color quality than the quirky white balance without effects) and have Skype get the video stream with applied effects.

Is there any way to do that?
As is, I cannot run two programs on `/dev/video0` simultanously.

Probably what is needed is retrieving the stream from `/dev/video0`, apply the effects, and forward as stream to a virtual device, like `/dev/video1`

Anybody knows how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a program called "WebcamStudio" which should do exactly what you are asking.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/webcamstudio/

Comment: can it broadcast direct to skype?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The above link takes you to a website that declares "REVOLUTIONARY TECHNOLOGY BOOSTS SKIN CARE RESULTS".

Answer (score 2):

The project is continuing on google code here:

http://code.google.com/p/webcamstudio/

There you can also find a ppa for daily builds, so you do not need to compile it yourself:

https://launchpad.net/~webcamstudio/+archive/webcamstudio-dailybuilds

Comment: Since this answer was posted, the project moved to https://sourceforge.net/projects/webcamstudio/ and was subsequently abandoned.

Comment: Yes, webcamstudio is no longer maintained. Isn't there any alternative?